# Spring Integration: Associating a header-enricher with a channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

In my application, several **jms:message-driven-channel-adapter** instances all output to the same internal channel. I want to associate a different **header-enricher** with each channel-adapter. Is there a way to do this?

The following code shows how to associate a header-enricher with the internal channel to which the jms:message-driven-channel-adapter outputs to:

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="J1" destination="Q1" channel="in1"/>
<int:header-enricher input-channel="in1" output-channel="out1">
     <int:header name="fromAdapter" value="1"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

However, this will not work in my scenario, in which all channel-adapter's use the same internal channel . It would be nice to be able to define the header-enricher inside of the channel-adapter. Is there another way to link the adapter and enricher together?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different header-enrichers should have different **input-channels** anyway. You can provide some routing logic and use `<gateway>` for request-reply flow for your header-enrichers:

```
<chain input-channel="in1" output-channel="out1">
    <gateway request-channel="enrichement"/>
</chain>

<router input-channel="enrichement">
    <mapping channel="he1" value=""/>
    ...
</router>

<header-enricher input-channel="he1">
...
</header-enricher>

<header-enricher input-channel="he2">
...
</header-enricher>
....
<header-enricher input-channel="heN">
...
</header-enricher>
```

HTH